# ComponentInstace undefined on NgbModal

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I'm breaking my head since yesterday night thinking why this code is not working

```
onOutletFeedback(content) {
    const modalRef  = this.modalService.open(content, {
      scrollable: false,
      size: 'md'
    });
    modalRef.componentInstance.contactId = this.contactId; //Facing issue at this line
    modalRef.componentInstance.url = environment.apiUrl;
    modalRef.result.then(
      result => {
        // on save click
      },
      reason => {
        // on dismiss
        console.log(`Dismissed with: ${reason}`);
      }
    );
  }
```

I'm always getting this error when I try to invoke my Modal.

[image]

My Modal Code

```
    <button (click)="onOutletFeedback(OutletFeedbackModal)"
                  class="btn btn-secondary"
                  placement="bottom"
                  ngbTooltip="Feedback" >
                  <i class="icon-comment"></i></button>

<ng-template #OutletFeedbackModal let-modal>
  <app-outlet-feedback [modal]="modal"></app-outlet-feedback>
</ng-template>
```

My ModalComponent Code

```
export class OutletFeedbackComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() modal: any;
  @Input() contactId: number;
```

Any help is appreciated I've checked the docs and every possible link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign input property value directly to app-outlet-feed try this:

```
<ng-template #OutletFeedbackModal let-modal>
     <app-outlet-feedback [contactId]="contactId" [modal]="modal"></app-outlet-feedback>
</ng-tempalte>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, here is the way to pass data to the content with ngdModal :

`this.modalRef['data'] = "any data you want to pass to ModalComp class";`

PS : 'componentInstance' is part of the angular testing API.

Comment: I changed to this... Now I'm not getting that error but still ContactId is undefined on the ModalComponent...

Comment: try to console.log `this.contactId` to make sure it isn't undefined

Comment: this I have checked... it is not undefined... it contains the value

Comment: did you change it to this : `this.modalRef['contactId'] = this.contactId` ? (check camelcase as your question include contactId and you just talk about ContactId)

Comment: Oh.. No No.. it is camelcase only contactId

Comment: i'm confused with the ng-template usage in your example as it isn't how the library is described inside the docs. You should try to recreate your modal following the docs : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngb-modal